# Is there a puppeteer function to retrieve all elements with the same selector and click on them not each one on the same time but one by one? ()

Tags: click, puppeteer, selector

I've started to study puppeteer a week ago.
I have to go through a grid done with angular and its ng-repeat. I must not modify this grid, so if you have a solution that require to modify the grid, unfortunately that's not possible. The grid is exactly the one in the last snippet i've added down this post. 
My goal is to retrieve all the img buttons identified by the selector '[title="Titolo FD"]', then click on the first one, make same operation on the opened window, close the window, then click on the second button, make the same operation previously done on the first button, close the second window, click on the third button and so on.

I've tried this code below

```
   for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        try {
            await page.waitForSelector('[title="Titolo FD"]');

            let list = await page.$$('[title="Titolo FD"]');
            let results = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                results.push(await (await list[j].getProperty('outerHTML')).jsonValue())
            }
            await results[i].click(); // this function here doesn't work for me
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(Console.FgRed, e.message);
        }
        await page.waitForTimeout(600);
    }
```

and with this i can retrieve the list of buttons i need but can't click on them.

Here's the grid i have.

```html
<div class="ui-grid-canvas">
<!-- ngRepeat: (rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index -->

<div ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}">
<div ui-grid-row="row" row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-005" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope">
<img src="/path/images/find.gif" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnClick3(row.entity.CId)" class="bottoneGriglia" title="TITOLO">
<img src="/path/images/img2.png" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnClick4(row.entity.CId)" class="bottoneGriglia" title="TITOLO FD"></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-006" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">00001</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-007" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">Tipo A</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-008" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">AC</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-009" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">CL</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00A" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">cf</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00B" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">02/10/2008 15:18:07</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00C" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope" title="Visualizza 1"> 
<a class="wx_link_button_blue ng-binding" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnAzione1(row.entity)">6</a><a></a></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00D" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope" title="Visualizza 2"> 
<a class="wx_link_button_blue ng-binding" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnAzione2(row.entity)">183</a><a></a></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid --></div></div><!-- end ngRepeat: (rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index -->

<div ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}">
<div ui-grid-row="row" row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-005" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope">
<img src="/path/images/find.gif" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnClick3(row.entity.CId)" class="bottoneGriglia" title="TITOLO">
<img src="/path/images/img2.png" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnClick4(row.entity.CId)" class="bottoneGriglia" title="TITOLO FD"></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-006" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">00002</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-007" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">Tipo B</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-008" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">AC</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-009" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">F SRL</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00A" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">piva</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00B" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">26/10/2008 18:45:15</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00C" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope" title="Visualizza 1"> 
<a class="wx_link_button_blue ng-binding" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnAzione1(row.entity)">3</a><a></a></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid -->
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00D" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope" title="Visualizza 2"> 
<a class="wx_link_button_blue ng-binding" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="grid.appScope.btnAzione2(row.entity)">5</a><a></a></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: (colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid --></div></div><!-- end ngRepeat: (rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index -->

<<row 3>>
...
<<row N>>

</div>
```

Thanks to you all!

Comment: It seems you push strings with HTML to `results`, so you cannot click on `results[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you intended to click on the page elements in `list`, and not the string elements in `results`, like so:

```
await list[i].click();
```